# How to Route IIS to Nested Default Document

Tags: iis, routes

I am trying host a site on `xyz.domain.com` in IIS, but the default document is at `/admin/admin.php`.

Therefore when I just enter the root domain (`xyz.domain.com`) I get an error.

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

I need to type the full path `xyz.domain.com/helpspot/admin.php` to load the site.

I have tried setting the default document to `/helpspot/admin.php`, but this isn't working properly.

I also tried re-routing the URL.

[image]

How can I direct to this document from `xyz.domain.com` using IIS?

Comment: Install URL Rewrite module and redirect such requests to the page.

Comment: When I tried this, the redirect seemed to work, but I got a `403: Access is denied` error.

Comment: "When I tried this"? What had you tried? Edit the question and add the details (such as the rule you created).

Comment: The question is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index.php in the webroot with the following to force redirect traffic from xyz.example.com/ to xyz.example.com/admin/ (it should use index.php automatically).

```
 <?php
header('Location: http://xyz.example.com/admin/' , true, 301);
exit ();
?>
```

Also make sure `index.php` is in the default documents list - no path, just filename.

Comment: Where does the switch from `index.php` to `admin.php` happen?

Comment: Missed that - either add `admin.php` as a default document, or adjust the path in the header call (so xyz.example.com/ will send traffic to xyz.example.com/admin/admin.php)

Comment: I'm getting a `404` error with ```<?php header('Location: https://sub.xyz.com/admin/admin.php' , true, 301); exit (); ?>``` and a default document of `admin.php` in the root directory.

Comment: 404 when accessing sub.xyz.com/ or after it redirects?

Comment: out of interest - are you able to change the webroot to the admin folder inside the current webroot? That would remove the need to redirect?